# Why is my partition showing as being in 3 parts?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, merge

I have a partition that is split into 3 parts, how can I merge them or just make them adjacent so they merge automatically?

[image: disk screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

Look at the disk type below "Disk 0" on the left side of your screenshot. It says that the disk is a [dynamic disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Disk_Manager) instead of the normal basic disk. Partitions on a dynamic disk don't have the normal blue color. Here's an example of both disk types

[image: Sample basic & dynamic disks]

Dynamic disk is the Windows counterpart of [Linux LVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_%28Linux%29) which adds flexibility to the disk configuration. It allows you to extend a partition into any free space on any dynamic disks, or add a software RAID (mirror, striped, RAID-5...) to the system. You can also see those options in the above screenshot. It looks like originally the Y: and G: drives above took the full space but then have been shrunk when someone needs more space for the A: drive, then A: is expanded to the newly free space

Since your volume is spanned across difference places on the disk, you can only merge it by copying data onto a different partition, move the other partitions to make space for the single new partition before recreating the partition. Even if you want to do that it's not quite safe to do, and there aren't a lot of partitioning tools that can operate on dynamic disks. The tools that are available are usually not free either

You can also convert from dynamic to basic, but you still need to make the partitions contiguous before converting. You must use 3rd party solutions because Windows' disk management can't convert dynamic disks back to back to basic disk without losing data. Here are some solutions

- [How to Change Dynamic Disk to Basic Disk Safely](https://www.easeus.com/partition-master/change-dynamic-disk-to-basic.html)
- [Convert dynamic disk to basic without losing data](https://www.diskpart.com/ddm-resource/convert-dynamic-disk-to-basic.html)
- [Two Ways to Convert Basic Disk to Dynamic Disk without Data Loss](https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmanager/convert-disk-to-dynamic.html)
- [Convert Dynamic Disk to Basic Disk](https://www.diskgenius.com/manual/convert-dynamic-disk-to-basic-disk.php)

If you aren't ready to take the risk and don't dual boot other OSes, just leave them as-is

For more information read

- [What Is Dynamic Disk | Everything About Windows Dynamic Disk](https://www.easeus.com/resource/dynamic-disk-recovery.htm)
- [Basic and Dynamic Disks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/basic-and-dynamic-disks)
- [Dynamic disks](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dynamic_disks)
- [What Are Basic & Dynamic Disks: Features, Differences, Conversion](https://www.partitionwizard.com/help/what-are-basic-and-dynamic-disks.html)

Answer (score 2):

Your disk is a
[Dynamic Disk](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/basic-and-dynamic-disks?redirectedfrom=MSDN#dynamic-disks).
Dynamic disk volumes can be composed of a set of noncontiguous extents on one or
multiple physical disks, all having the same drive-letter.
(Remark: `A:` is traditionally reserved for floppy drives.)

As long as the disk is dynamic, you cannot merge the three parts of the partition `A`.
Nor will the parts merge automatically if placed in adjacent position
(which you may do using a partition editor).

You wouldn't have had this problem if the disk was a
[Basic disk](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/basic-and-dynamic-disks?redirectedfrom=MSDN#basic-disks),
but according to Microsoft's article
[Change a dynamic disk back to a basic disk](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/change-a-dynamic-disk-back-to-a-basic-disk),
converting a dynamic disk to basic would cause all data to be lost.

The only solution would be to either :

- Save all data, reformat the disk and partition it as you like,
  perhaps also converting it to Basic (or not)
- Leave the situation as-is, if everything works correctly.