# Merge two partitions which contain different OSes

Tags: windows, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, disk-space

I have two OSes installed in my laptop, Windows 10 and Ubuntu. Now, I want to remove Ubuntu and merge that partition with the other partition in Windows. How am I supposed to do it?

This is how the disk management looks like

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You *want to remove Ubuntu and merge that partition with the other partition* but which one? Drive F: or E:?

Nevertheless I should note that you have some serious problem by having two [EFI System Partitions (ESP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition)

[image: Partition list]

Partitions 1 and 6 are both ESPs which violate the rule that there must be only one in a single disk. So you should remove partition 6. Partition 8 (the 100.71 GB one) is probably the one with Ubuntu. So if you remove both partitions 6 and 8 then you have a free space that you can extend drive F: into. Just delete them and right click on F: then click on *Extend Volume...*

But if you want to merge the free space into E: then I have a bad news for you: **Physical partitions must be contiguous**. That means you can't merge partitions that aren't right next to each other. Anyway it's doable with [*logical partitions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_volume_management). They add another disk abstraction level so they can spread in various locations. That also means there'll be obvious disadvantage: performance would be worse performance for simple JBOD configurations

If you really want to extend drive E: then in Windows there are several built-in logical disk solutions such as [dynamic disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Disk_Manager) and [Storage Spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Features_new_to_Windows_8#Storage). The easiest way to achieve what you want is to use dynamic disk, like in this question [Why is my partition showing as being in 3 parts?](https://superuser.com/q/1538205/241386)

- Right click the disk in disk management > *Convert to Dynamic Disk...*
- Delete the partitions you want
- Right click the partition you want to expand, select *Extend Volume...*, then choose the newly available space(s) after deleting partitions

An example with a volume in 3 different partitions

[image: Dynamic disk example]

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, Windows Disk Management doesn't allow you to merge non adjacent partitions. You might be able to merge partitions 1,6,7,8 to E: but not C:. Though before merging you will have to format those partitions.

Alternatively, you can download softwares online to merge non adjacent partitions. There are plenty available online.

Comment: it's not related to Windows Disk Management at all because it's a feature of the [partition table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning#Partition_table). No partition table allows a partition to scatter around the disk. Only logical disk formats like dynamic disk (which is supported by Windows Disk Management) or LVM allow such a partition

Comment: who said that partition 1 can be merged into E:? It's the ESP which will render your PC not bootable if deleted. Besides, it's at the start of the disk while E is several partitions **after** that. 6, 7, 8 are also **after** F: so how can they be merged into E:? `you can download softwares online to merge non adjacent partitions` this is just nonsense. If the partition format doesn't allow it then **no partitioning software can merge those partitions**